# Is there a difference between きらい and がすきではありません?

Tags: word-choice

Simply put Pimsluer says to use がすきではありません to express a dislike, but Human Japanese uses きらい, is there a difference?

Comment: oh sorry I meant　がすきありません

Comment: Also Pimsluer is a mostly audio based learning program (you don't actually see anything in writing until lesson 2 when they get into kana), not that it makes a difference

Comment: I would say it's a difference of degree. It's the same difference as saying, `I don't like fish.` and `I hate fish.` respectively.

Comment: I thought they both where along the likes of **I dislike fish** and to say **I hate fish** you would have to use だいきらい

Comment: 大嫌い(だいきらい) shows extreme disdain for something. I LOATHE fish (worse that hating them). I would agree with @dotnetN00b on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nuance of 好きではない depends largely on the context and the tone of the speaker's voice.

People often use 好きではない when they actually *hate* something/someone, because 嫌い is a very strong and offensive word. Someone who says 嫌い too often is someone who is disliked by others. 好きではない can act as an euphemistic expression, so to say. 苦手【にがて】だ (be not good at ～) is an even more euphemistic expression, but it's still easy to express your hate on the target with this phrase, if you say it with an appropriate facial expression.

On the other hand, people can use 好きではない when they literally "do not like" something:

> 「寿司は好きですか?」「好きではないですね。」
>   "Do you like sushi?" "Not particularly. / Not really."

Here, the person who answered does not particularly love nor hate sushi.

My understanding is that 嫌い is more like *dislike* and 大嫌い is closer to *hate*, but these should depend on the context, too.

By the way, there is also a verb 憎【にく】む, which is usually translated as *to hate*, but this is a *really* strong word which refers to a long-held grudge on someone. Don't say, for example 私は[納豆【なっとう】](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natt%C5%8D)を憎んでいます, because it sounds almost like a joke.

Answer (score 2):

As @dotnetN00b mentions in the comments, in general, the difference is between dislike and hate. Of course in some instances, individual interpretation may have an effect on how one chooses to use each word and what context to use them.

> A basic and non-complete comparison of the words (as I understand them) is below.
>
> - 大好き > Love / Really Like
> - 好き > Like
> - 好きではありません OR 好きじゃない > Dislike
> - 嫌い > Hate
> - 大嫌い > Loathe / Really Hate

I would assume that where different, what each teaching manual / book etc. teaches as it's definition, is largely open to the liberties taken by the editor.

However, as I mentioned, this is a brief, basic comparison. There does happens to be times when 嫌い means dislike. For example 好き嫌い (Likes and Dislikes) and it really depends on the context and the person speaking.

A:マヨネーズ好き？嫌い？

B:あまり好きじゃないな～

Comment: Too simplistic a list, that is.  Japanese speakers often use 嫌い and 大嫌い more freely and casually than English speakers use "hate" and "loathe" respectively.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I just realised there are plenty of times I use it myself, I will update my answer however I think @naruto's did a more thorough job.